# Replace table instead of append jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following code segment that grabs user input from an HTML form, and then reads a CSV file, and grabs corresponding data to display to my website. If I submit another 'searchTerm' after the initial one in my form, it appends the new row of data from the csv file to the page, and I want it to replace instead. When I try to replace the row however, all my data vanishes.

```
function submitForm(){
    nameValue = document.getElementById("searchTerm").value;

    //document.getElementById("display-results").innerHTML = nameValue;
    location.href = "#page-3";

    function arrayToTable(tableData) {
        var table = $('<table></table>');
        $(tableData).each(function (i, rowData) {
            var row = $('<tr></tr>');
            
            $(rowData).each(function (j, cellData) {
              if (cellData == nameValue) {
                row.append($('<td>'+rowData[1]+'</td>'));
              }
            });
            table.append(row);
        });
        return table;
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "mainFile.csv",
        success: function (data) {
            parsed = Papa.parse(data).data;
            $('#display-results').append(arrayToTable(Papa.parse(data).data));
        }
    });
}
```

As you can see in the image, it appends the content rather than replacing the first array.

[image: This is a simple example of how my code performs, it appends a new row of data instead of replacing the old one.]

Answer (score 0):

Remember to just replace the table, not the entire display-results element (except the first time you build the table).

```js
if($('#display-results table').length === 0) // append if you haven't built the table yet
  $('#display-results').append(arrayToTable(Papa.parse(data).data));
else
  $('#display-results table').replaceWith(arrayToTable(Papa.parse(data).data));
```

Comment: thank you @tlong314 that helped a lot. Since I am returning a list of data, do you know how to access index [0], [1], etc from this Papa.parse(data).data list? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding the question. You could save Papa.parse(data).data array beforehand to access the elements later. If you are asking how to access the table data after returning it from arrayToTable, you could parse through with table.find("tr").each(function(i) {  console.log( $(this).find("td").text() )  }) // replacing console.log with whatever you are doing with the text